# SSRS2008R2 report times out, but the underlying query executes in the Management Studio

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

A customer of mine recently moved servers and the new server has SQL2008R2.  His old server was SQL2005.  The new server has substantially better CPU, RAM, and disk performance than the old, but several reports time out while executing.

When I run the underlying query in the SQL Management Studio, the query executes in sub-second time.

The exact error message returned via the Report Manager UI is:

An error occurred within the report server database. This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database. (rsReportServerDatabaseError)
Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

It must be noted that this database is not just analytical; it's also fairly transactional, although the transaction volume is not exceptionally high.

What can I do to improve the performance of the SSRS query engine?  Are there settings in the data source I can adjust, or in the SSRS config files?

Comment: I should also add that the report in question, when run with the parameters in question, only returns 50 rows of data.

Comment: More info: I just installed SP1 for SQL2008R2 and the problem persists.  I notice a definite correlation between running this report and the memory consumption of the SSRS process going through the roof.  In fact, the system event log couldn't even create the report service appdomain because the process ran out of memory.